# Pages, Custom Posts & Custom Taxonomy defining slug structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

I'm struggling to set up the structure of my wordpress site correctly so that the slugs, work correctly.

The page & custom post setup works fine and is as follows:

```
Archive for fruits (page):
- site.com/fruits
Singular fruits (custom post)
---- site.com/fruit/apple
---- site.com/fruit/pear

Archive for Veg (page):
- site.com/vegtables
Singular fruits (custom post)
---- site.com/vegtable/spud
---- site.com/vegtable/carrot
```

I would like to include a custom taxonomy, say colour, and using the plural have the following permalink:

```
Archive page for fruits by colour
- site.com/fruits/colour/green
- site.com/fruits/colour/red
```

I have been going round in circles trying to figure this out, but I believe the correct method would be:

```
 Create a page template for the custom post  custom taxonomy archive, e.g
 page-fruit-color.php
 and create a page for the above.

 Set permalinks so all request for
 - site.com/fruits/colour/%colour%
 go to the above page
```

Could some please clarify that this would be the best method, if would they have any pointers as to how I may actually achieve this? If it isn't, could someone please suggest the preferred method.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the cases you describe are handled by the post type archive, post type single, and taxonomy term archive pages that are all automatically generated (depending on arguments) when you register your post type and taxonomy.

```
function wpd_add_custom_types() {

    // register fruit post type
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Fruit',
        'has_archive' => 'fruits', // all posts of type fruit
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'fruit' ) // single fruit
    );
    register_post_type( 'fruit', $args );

    // register colour taxonomy
    $args = array(
        'label' => 'Colour',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'fruits/colour' ) // all fruits of colour
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'colour', 'fruit', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_custom_types' );
```

Comment: cheers for the reply. How do I get the taxonomy rewrite slug to work for more than one post type? Eg fruit and vegetables

Comment: that's a little more complicated, since a taxonomy only has a single URL. you'll have to [add another rewrite rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) which sets the `post_type` and `colour` query vars for vegetables and the requested colour. you'll also have to add a [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter to limit the `fruits/colour` URLs to just the `fruit` post type.

Comment: Is it definitely possible for me to have a page with the same slug that the has_archive points towards? This causes a conflict as wordpress is looking for the archive as opposed to the page?

Comment: if you want to use a page, set `has_archive` to false.